# Building ninja from the binaries ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, cmake, ubuntu-18.04, ninja, precompiled-binaries

I am new to the process of building packages from their binaries, and I feel like I am missing something conceptually. I built ninja version 1.10.2 from the binaries using cmake and it seemed to work fine, but whenever I check ninja --version it returns the older version. What final step am I missing to ensure that its using the newly installed version? Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Downloaded the tar.gz from here https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
2. Extracted the files to a directory I made in my home called ninja

   `tar xvzf ~/Downloads/"filename" -C ~/ninja`
3. It extracted fine and now if I navigate to `~/ninja/ninja-1.10.2/` there is a READ.ME with the following instructions on building with cmake

   `cmake -Bbuild-cmake -H.`

   `cmake --build-cmake`

So I follow those directions while in `~/ninja/ninja-1.10.2/`. I get no errors and now there is a build-cmake directory! What am i supposed to do next?

I am guessing I have the new version installed but I haven't pointed to it so ninja doesn't know where this new version is / needs to load it. How do I do that?

Comment: As usual, you need to add directory with your new `ninja` executable into the PATH variable.

Comment: could you provide a little more detail about this? Or a link that describes this process more generally. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: See that answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3820